# How to use recursion inside a class function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a class function that deals with matrices or a list within a list. Sort of like a calculator that looks like this:

```
class RealMat:
    def __init__(self, mat):
        self.mat = mat

    def __add__(self, other):
        if len(self.mat) != len(other.mat) or len(self.mat[0]) != len(self.mat[0]):
            return None
        result = self.mat
        for i in range(len(self.mat)):
            for j in range(len(self.mat[0])):
                result[i][j] = self.mat[i][j] + other.mat[i][j]
        return RealMat(result)


    def __sub__(self, other):
        if len(self.mat) != len(other.mat) or len(self.mat[0]) != len(self.mat[0]):
            return None
        result = self.mat
        for i in range(len(self.mat)):
            for j in range(len(self.mat[0])):
                result[i][j] = self.mat[i][j] - other.mat[i][j]
        return RealMat(result)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            for x in range(len(self.mat)):
                for y in range(len(self.mat[0])):
                    self.mat[x][y] = self.mat[x][y] * other
            return RealMat(self.mat)
        if len(self.mat[0])!=len(other.mat):
            return None
        column=0
        result=[[0]*len(self.mat) for i in range(len(other.mat[0]))]
        for x in range(len(other.mat[0])):
            row = 0
            for x in range(len(self.mat)):
                total = 0
                i = 0
                for x in range(len(self.mat[0])):
                    total += self.mat[row][i] * other.mat[i][column]
                    i += 1
                result[row][column] = total
                row += 1
            column += 1
        return RealMat(result)

    def __rmul__(self, factor):
        for x in range(len(self.mat)):
                for y in range(len(self.mat[0])):
                    self.mat[x][y] = self.mat[x][y] * factor
        return RealMat(self.mat)

    def __pow__(self, n):
        if len(self.mat) != len(self.mat[0]):
            return None
        if n == 0:
             identity = [[1 if i == j else 0 for i in range(len(self.mat))] for j in range(len(self.mat))]
            return RealMat(identity)
        result = RealMat(self.mat)
        for x in range(n-1):
            result = result * RealMat(self.mat)
        return result

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if len(self.mat) != len(other.mat) or len(self.mat[0]) != len(other.mat[0]):
            return False
        for x in range(len(self.mat)):
            for y in range(len(self.mat[0])):
                if self.mat[x][y] != other.mat[x][y]:
                    return False
        return True


    def getMatrixMinor(self,i,j):
        return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (self.mat[:i]+self.mat[i+1:])]

    def getMatrixDeternminant(self):
        if len(self.mat) == 2:
            return self.mat[0][0]*self.mat[1][1]-self.mat[0][1]*self.mat[1][0]

        determinant = 0
        for c in range(len(self.mat)):
            determinant += ((-1)**c)*self.mat[0][c]*getMatrixDeternminant(getMatrixMinor(self.mat,0,c))
        return determinant
```

All the other code works fine and I'm happy with it but I can't seem to make my determinant finder code to work

```
def getMatrixMinor(self,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (self.mat[:i]+self.mat[i+1:])]
```

This code gets me the minor matrix while this:

```
def getMatrixDeternminant(self):
    if len(self.mat) == 2:
        return self.mat[0][0]*self.mat[1][1]-self.mat[0][1]*self.mat[1][0]

    determinant = 0
    for c in range(len(self.mat)):
        determinant += ((-1)**c)*self.mat[0][c]*getMatrixDeternminant(getMatrixMinor(self.mat,0,c))
    return determinant
```

Solves the determinant of nxn matrix. However it keeps saying "getMatrixDeternminant is not defined" when I try to recurse it. Maybe because it is inside a class? I just got into OOP so I am not well versed in this. Can someone point out what I did wrong?

edit* I tried using the self.getMatrixDeternminant()

```
def getMatrixMinor(self,m,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (m[:i]+m[i+1:])]

def getMatrixDeternminant(self):
    if len(self.mat) == 2:
        return self.mat[0][0]*self.mat[1][1]-self.mat[0][1]*self.mat[1][0]

    determinant = 0
    for c in range(len(self.mat)):
        determinant += ((-1)**c)*self.mat[0][c]*self.getMatrixDeternminant(self.getMatrixMinor(self.mat,0,c))
    return determinant
```

it says:

```
TypeError: getMatrixDeternminant() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Edit**: I actually got the code from somewhere and tried to implement it in my class. This is the original code:

```
def getMatrixMinor(m,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (m[:i]+m[i+1:])]

def getMatrixDeternminant(m):
    #base case for 2x2 matrix
    if len(m) == 2:
        return m[0][0]*m[1][1]-m[0][1]*m[1][0]

    determinant = 0
    for c in range(len(m)):
        determinant += ((-1)**c)*m[0][c]*getMatrixDeternminant(getMatrixMinor(m,0,c))
    return determinant
```

Comment: Did you tried *self.getMatrixDeterminant()* instead of that? Tell if that works

Comment: I edited my post I did self.getMatrixDeternminant() but it says type error

Comment: What do you mean by passing self to the second function? I'm sorry I haven't studied this deeply yet

Comment: Your code has *two* problems. First, you are using the method unqualified – ``getMatrixDeternminant`` refers to an *enclosing* object/function, only ``self.getMatrixDeternminant``/``RealMatrix.getMatrixDeternminant`` refer to the method. Second, you are trying to use ``getMatrixDeternminant`` both as a method (working on ``self``) and as a classmethod (working on the result of ``self.getMatrixMinor``). That cannot work.

Comment: Ohhh alright so I gotta modify this code somehow. Can you give me a hint that can help me solve this?

Comment: Just for testing grounds, try adding ***self.*** In front of both getMatrixDeterminant and getMatrixMinor

Comment: "TypeError: getMatrixDeternminant() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" This keeps popping up hahaha

Comment: I added the original code I based the matrix determinant from

Comment: If you attempt to provide a minimal verifiable example your problem will go away. This is totally a case where there is too much distraction.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getMatrixDeternminant` [sic] calculates the determinant of the current object (`self`). However, your algorithm requires calculating the determinant of *other* matrices.

Therefore, first keep the algorithm as it was originally (usually you would make it a static method or keep it outside the class). Then, from your method, call that algorithm passing it your current matrix.