# how to use Recursion in a function (with self as first argument) inside a Class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, recursion

I tried solving fibonacci sequence using ***recursion*** in Python but the required solution has to be in the following format :

```
class Solution:
    def fib(self, n: int) -> int:
    # code here recursively utilizing fib(arg1,arg2)
```

This was my best attempt :

```
class Solution:
    def fib(self, n: int) -> int:
       if n == 0 :
           return n
       if n == 1 or n==2 : 
           return 1
       return fib(fib,n-1) + fib(fib,n-2)
```

But this yielded following Runtime Error :

```
NameError: name 'fib' is not defined
    return fib(fib,n-1) + fib(fib,n-2)
Line 7 in fib (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().fib(param_1)
Line 33 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 44 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

I came across this related question : [How to use recursion inside a class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857267/how-to-use-recursion-inside-a-class-function) but I was interested in finding a more generic python guide so as to be able to use RECURSION inside a class in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fib` is an instance method in your case, use it in a proper way:

```
class Solution:
    def fib(self, n: int) -> int:
        if n == 0:
            return n
        if n <= 2:
            return 1
        return self.fib(n - 1) + self.fib(n - 2)

print(Solution().fib(10))   # 55
```